# Shell: Is it possible to give a string as a file to a command?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, zsh, command-substitution

Suppose we have a command,

```
eval-some-language —-path=<filename>
```

And we want to do something like this:

```
eval-some-language —-path=“say hello world!
 exit 3”
```

I think the following solution might work for one file, and if stdin is not used for sth else:

```
eval-some-language —-path=“/dev/stdin” <<<“say hello ...”
```

Does this work with all commands? How portable is it? (macOS?)

And is there any other ways to do this?

Update: Both my solution, the accepted answer, and zsh’s =() don’t work if the file needs to be executable. :(

Comment: This is an XY problem. Why not ask what you want to accomplish? What do you want to do to each download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
eval-some-language --path=<(echo "hello world")
```

<() will generate a file descriptor, tied to the output of the command and pass it as /dev/fd/xxx. E.g:

```
$ echo <(echo aaa)
/dev/fd/63

$ echo <(echo test) <(echo second test)
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
```

For slightly more information see the "Process Substittution" section in `man bash`

Comment: Sadly it again gave me an error saying the file isn’t executable. :(

Comment: That's probably unrelated. What exactly did you run?

Comment: `aria2c “some-url” —on-download-complete <(echo “touch nnn6”)` and the — is typed wrongly on my iPad.

Comment: --on-download-complete requires an executable script to execute. That's way different than just a file and certainly doesn't work with your solution either. You need an actual file if you want to execute it. Your best solution is to generate a temporary file with mktemp, make it executable and pass that as a parameter.

Comment: @jimmij, they seem to want an executable file that their program executes once it downloads something. I don't think that can ever be possible because executing a program with execve() will require a real file with executable permissions.